# Not able to download pdf-file (stored in binary data format) from Mongo-db using React JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, file-upload

I used express-fileuplod for uploading the pdf file on Mongodb. I am facing problem to download that pdf file on front end.

I'm getting this prompt after downloading the pdf: ["Error. Failed to load PDF document"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYf5P.png)

form-data on MongoDB:

```
_id: ObjectId('63b7494295b850d0452a6a81')                                     
username: "sita"                                                                 
email: "sita@gmail.com"                                                            
dob: 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00                                                
city: "city"                                                                  
address: "add"                                                                   
services: Array                                                                     
0: "Demat"                                                                            
pancard: Object                                                                 
    Data:BinData(0,'JVBERi0xLjcKCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwKL0ZpbHRlciAvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUKL0xlbmd0aCAzMDEzNQo+PgpzdHJlYW0KeJztvU1247gS…')                                                
    ContentType: "application/pdf"                                                   
createdAt: 2023-01-05T22:03:46.893+00:00                                       
updatedAt: 2023-01-05T22:03:46.893+00:00                                             
__v: 0
```

[reactjs code:]

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchClient = async () =>{
        const res = await axios.get('/users/sita@gmail.com');
        setData(res.data.pancard.Data.data);
        setContentType(res.data.pancard.contentType)
    }

   fetchClient()       
},[userdetail]);


const downloadPdf = (filename, contentType) => {
      const file = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
      saveAs(file, "pancard.pdf") 
      //const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      //window.open(fileURL);       
  };
```

Calling downloadpdf() method here in JSX

> <button class="btn btn-primary button" onClick={downloadPdf('pancard', contentType)}>Download

The file is also getting downloaded infinite times in loop

Comment: please provide code so that we can check where is the issue

Comment: Please show the code where you get the `data` variable in `new Blob([data]`

Comment: @Rintu Banerjee i have provided the code now

Comment: @hungtran273 , the data is a binary array of pdf file coming from mongo-db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

That `data` is only an Array, we need to convert to Uint8Array

```
const file = new Blob([new Uint8Array(data)], { type: contentType });
saveAs(file, "pancard.pdf")
```

---

**Solution 2**

We have to serve file on another route, it can not be sent with json data

backend

```
// Example in Express
app.get('/get_file', (req, res) => {
  // Query user
  res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="test.pdf"');
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  res.send(user.pancard);
}
```

frontend

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/get_file')
      .then(res => res.blob())
      .then(data => {
        saveAs(data, 'test.pdf');
      })
```

With large file, Solution 2 is better thanks to the `Content-Disposition` header. File data is transferred safely with this header (I don't really understand the underlying mechanism, please research further)

---

Also notice 2 things:

- It is not recommend to save file data directly into database. Instead, save as static file and only store the path to database.
- If file size exceed 16mb. We need to use GridFS for Mongo. More details: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/gridfs/

Comment: It worked, now I am able to download the pdf successfully. I fetched contentType of pancard: `setContentType(res.data.pancard.ContentType); ` and assigned it to the contentType variable and used that variable, now it can retrieve file type. Earlier the second parameter of BLOB was null, so it was also one of the reason I wasn't able to view the pdf.    Thank-you @hungtran273